# What to type in ASP.NET when you want to make sure that a button is clicked

Tags: asp.net

I don't seem to know how to correctly write bn_pwd.Click and to make it work. Please help me.

```
protected void bn_pwd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)   
    {
       if (bn_pwd.Click == true)
            {
                lb_showpwd.Visible = true;
                tb_Spwd.Visible = true;
                lb_showcfmpwd.Visible = true;
                tb_Scfmpwd.Visible = true;
            }
        else
        {
            lb_showpwd.Visible = false;
            tb_Spwd.Visible = false;
            lb_showcfmpwd.Visible = false;
            tb_Scfmpwd.Visible = false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you talking about a button or checkbox? What is the definition of your button in the aspx file?

Answer (score 0):

When the bn_pwd_Click function is fired, it means that the button was clicked. What you want to do with `bn_pwd.Click == true` ?

Maybe you should use a variable to store the state of the controls you want to apply.

Answer (score 0):

What you have will work (minus some unnecessary code), assuming you have a button with `OnClick="bn_pwd_Click"`:

```
<asp:Button ID="bn_pwd" OnClick="bn_pwd_Click" Text="Submit" runat="server" />
```

Alternatively, you can declare the `Click` event in the code behind (and not have it in the code-front as above). Personally, I like having it on the code-front side.

```
bn_pwd.Click += bn_pwd_Click;
```

Now, when the button is clicked, the page will post-back (your `Page_Load` will execute again), and *then* `bn_pwd_Click` will execute. So you only need this:

```
protected void bn_pwd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{   
    lb_showpwd.Visible = true;
    tb_Spwd.Visible = true;
    lb_showcfmpwd.Visible = true;
    tb_Scfmpwd.Visible = true;
}
```

Because that function only ever runs when the button is clicked. I assume the visibilities of all of those controls should be set to false to begin with. Either in code front or in `Page_Load`.

From your question, it seems like you need to review the [ASP.NET Page Life Cycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx) and could also benefit from some tutorials, like at [ASP.net](http://www.asp.net/web-forms).